# apache php - X-SendFile with Byte Range

Tags: apache2.2

I have Apache 2.2.8 installed on a server, and I'm trying to use `X-SendFile` to deliver video files.

Unfortunately some devices, like iPads, seem to require `Byte Range` in order to serve the files, but I cannot get `Accept-Ranges` to work with `X-SendFile`.

Here's the code

```php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_name) . '"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("X-Sendfile: $file_name");
```

I'd like to avoid the overhead and complexity caused by sending the byte chunks from php.

Comment: The module home page says it has support for ranges: https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ see Useful? > Benefits

Comment: If it does, why don't you add your comment as an answer? :) @schmunk

Comment: Because I haven't found a solution for the problem, just the info, that is should be supported.

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: have you tried using the correct content type and not seving it as an attachment/download?